# Output convert to text

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

With this code i get the id (1,2 or 3) But i want to convert these number to text (1 = open, 2 = closed and 3 = busy) i've tried a lot of things but really nothing works.
I Hoppe u guys can help me out!

```
 <?php 
                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ");
                            $status = mysql_query("UPDATE posts JOIN categories ON posts.cat_ID = categories.id SET posts.status = categories.title WHERE ID='$ID'");
                            while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $cat['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $cat['title']; ?></option>
                        <?php    

                            }

                        ?>
```

Comment: I don't see nay error in the code. So I can only guess: Is 'title' really the column name (also keep an eye on letter case)? Can you post an excerpt of the output you get? What is the UPDATE query doing there, it isn't used for output and setting posts.status to categories.title seems strange to me.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array with the values, and then use that:

```
$states = array(
    1 => 'open',
    2 => 'closed',
    3 => 'busy'
);

while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $states[$cat['ID']]; ?>"><?php echo $cat['title']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: i've tried that allready. with that code the output is allways 0. but thanks.